# ERROR: bind message has 9914 parameter formats but 0 parameters

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using PostgresSQL and I'm trying to remove all the data that I have in the columns (my entity is composed of `id` and `name`), but when I run the code, an error message appears.

This is the code (I'm using NestJs and TypeOrm):

```
    @Injectable()
export class ClearLinioBrands {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(LinioBrand)
    private linioBrandRepo: Repository<LinioBrand>,
  ) {}
  async execute(): Promise<void> {
    const existingBrands = await this.linioBrandRepo.find();
    await this.linioBrandRepo.remove(existingBrands);
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error on the console:

```
ERROR: bind message has 9914 parameter formats but 0 parameters
```

There are 115900 rows in this table, is that the reason for this behavior? What should I do?

Answer (score 21):

Just in case you were still looking for an answer:
I ran into the same issue using Nestjs and TypeORM. There is a limit to the amount of placeholders in the query. You can specify `{chunk: <chunkSize>}`

I found that [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3044#issuecomment-451517241)

So f.e.:

```
await this.linioBrandRepo.remove(existingBrands, {chunk: 100});
```

Comment: This appears to be a postgresql limitation. I encounter the same thing using a different query generator. Splitting a huge insert into chunks helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Emeka No, that's a client limitation. PostgreSQL supports up to 65535 query parameters.